# Отправка массива с помощью retrofit kotlin

Tags: kotlin, retrofit

[Body]
[
  "2011006095127",
  "2011006095134",
  "2011006095141",
  "2011006095158"
]
хочу отправить вот такой массив на сервер, но не знаю как это сделать
котлин только осваиваю.

Comment: А на Java знаете как?

Comment: Очень общий вопрос получает очень общий ответ... Если сервер готов, то возьмите библиотеку retrofit, разберитесь и отправляйте. Если и сервера нет, то сначала попытайтесь обойтись гуглом и своей головой, и если что-то не получится, тогда уже пишите сюда